# PostgreSQL - add extra variable to a set returned by a query

Tags: postgresql

I have a situation where I am returning a set of values from a postgre table like this

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT sale_set.sau_price_median AS avg_sale, sale_set.area_range_id AS area_range FROM 

(SELECT apart_comp_sale_price_est.sau_price_median, apart_comp_sale_price_est.area_range_id
FROM apart_comp_sale_price_est
WHERE
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.county_id = _county_id) AND
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.parish_id = _parish_id) AND
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.city_id = _city_id) AND
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.precint_id = _precint_id)
ORDER BY apart_comp_sale_price_est.precint_id NULLS LAST,
     apart_comp_sale_price_est.city_id NULLS LAST,
     apart_comp_sale_price_est.parish_id NULLS LAST,
     apart_comp_sale_price_est.county_id NULLS LAST
LIMIT 6) AS sale_set

ORDER BY sale_set.area_range_id;
```

This works as needed and returns me 6 rows of values, two variables in each row.

QUESTION: 
I have a constant variable: _const ='constant';

How do I add this independent variable (_const) to the set as a third variable. It so that the returning table would look like this

### avg_sale | area_range | const

and the const would repeat itself on each row (it doesn't need to but I see this as the only logical solution).

Do you have any advice for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as easy as just adding it in the select query, if you want to return a true for all of them then do `true AS _const` or `'string_value' AS _const` for a string

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT sale_set.sau_price_median AS avg_sale, sale_set.area_range_id AS area_range, 'constant' AS _const 
FROM 

(SELECT apart_comp_sale_price_est.sau_price_median, apart_comp_sale_price_est.area_range_id
FROM apart_comp_sale_price_est
WHERE
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.county_id = _county_id) AND
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.parish_id = _parish_id) AND
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.city_id = _city_id) AND
    (apart_comp_sale_price_est.precint_id = _precint_id)
ORDER BY apart_comp_sale_price_est.precint_id NULLS LAST,
     apart_comp_sale_price_est.city_id NULLS LAST,
     apart_comp_sale_price_est.parish_id NULLS LAST,
     apart_comp_sale_price_est.county_id NULLS LAST
LIMIT 6) AS sale_set

ORDER BY sale_set.area_range_id;
```

Comment: There are three `sale_set.` and ten(!) `apart_comp_sale_price_est.` in a short simply query. All completely useless. I suppose there is more garbage than useful characters. No offence, I just do not understand what for?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess that will happen when you are learning PostgreSQL and don't fully understand where you must and should not specify the parent entity. Work in progress...